# Finding the last page a user was on

Tags: php, session

I have four pages: `cart.php`, `checkout1.php`, `checkout2.php`, and `checkout3.php`. A summary of their function is below:

```
cart.php //display items and quantities in cart with option for coupon code
checkout1.php //input of user address
checkout2.php //order summary
checkout3.php //order placed into SQL
```

Things are kept in the cart via `$_SESSION`, but between each page I am using `$_POST` to bring information from one to the next. My concern is when a user just goes to `www.site.com/checkout2.php` from their address bar, for example, as it will display an empty page (but still allow them to continue to `checkout3.php` and waste SQL space). On each of the pages I redirect to `index.php` if the cart is empty (eg. you type in `checkout2.php` in the address bar on an empty cart, it won't display the bit of code that lets you continue), but if there are contents in `$_SESSION` but not `$_POST`, I'm not sure how to prevent users from screwing things up.

I thought maybe using something like `isset()`, but I would like something along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
//on checkout2.php
if (previouspage != "./checkout1.php") {
    echo "There was an error.";
} else {
    //display correct page
}
```

I know there exists `$_SERVER['HTTP-REFERER']` or something along those lines, but my understanding is that not every browser supports this and it doesn't give a concise locationo of the referring page (eg. will say user came from `www.site.com` vs. `www.site.com/checkout1.php`)

Comment: See [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: So you are suggesting placing `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` into a `$_SESSION` variable and checking that on the 2nd page?

Comment: Exactly. Give it a try, and post back should you encounter any problems.

Comment: ra_htial uses the same method but instead of checking for `$_SESSION["page"] == "page"`, it is done with numbers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a simple approach as follows:

1- create a session variable called **steps**

2- once the user moves from one step to the other increase the variable by 1

3- on the top of each page check the steps variable if it's valid for that page

**For example:**

Cart.php

```
$_SESSION['steps'] = 1;
```

checkout.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION["steps"]) && $_SESSION["steps"] == 1){
    //die or redirect
}

//once all the logic execute properly
$_SESSION['steps'] = 2;
```

checkout2.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION["steps"]) && $_SESSION["steps"] == 2){
    //die or redirect
}

//once all the logic execute properly
$_SESSION['steps'] = 3;
```

checkout3.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION["steps"]) && $_SESSION["steps"] == 3){
    //die or redirect
}

//once all the logic execute properly
unset($_SESSION['steps']);
```

Comment: Cheers, this works perfectly. I just wanted to add in case someone with a similar issue comes up and reads your answer, that I changed the `if` conditions to `if(isset($_SESSION["steps"]) && $_SESSION["steps"] == num)` in my actual code to prevent error messages.

Comment: @Malcolm thats wont work all the time since if it's 1 it should redirect to `cart.php`

Comment: @ra_htial That's true, I removed my comment once I realized that